# Nothing happens when calling the function

Tags: matlab

I am working on a Matlab project. I have listed the instructions in the comments in the code.

```
%This function will take the number that you put in and give you a 
%value 
%of how many numbers it had to do the mathematical operations on to  
%get to the number 1. 
%If the number inputted is even, start by dividing it by 2. If the
%result is even, then repeat the process. If the result is odd, then
%multiply the result by 3 and then add 1. Keep doing this until the
%number is 1. 

function [s, m] = collatz(num) 
%INPUTS
%num = the number that the user inputs
%OUTPUTS
%s = the number of steps it took to reach the number 1
%m = the maximum value in that list

veclist = []; %Creates an empty vector which will hold the list of       
              %numbers

while num ~= 0 %While the number is not equal to zero 
    if num > 0 %If this number is greater than zero
        if rem(num,2) == 0 %If the number is even
            num = num/2; %divide the number by 2
            veclist = [veclist, num]; %add the number to the vector

        else %This says if the number is odd
            num = (num*3) + 1; %Multiply that number by 3 and add 1
            veclist = [veclist, num]; %Add that number to the list 

        end 
    end
end

s = length(veclist) %shows how many elements are in the vector
m = max(veclist) %shows the max value in the vector

end
```

Can somebody tell me why nothing happens when calling the function.

I say "collatz(5)" and it returns nothing

Comment: Sounds like your active folder is incorrect (see `pwd`), or the filename is wrong (should probably be `collatz.m`).

Comment: @Dev-iL How do I change my active folder? I have my filename set as    collatz.m

Comment: Generally using `cd`, ex: `cd c:\path\to\collatz`.

Comment: @Dev-iL but where do I enter this command?

Comment: Where does one enter commands in MATLAB?

Comment: @Dev-iL oh yeah the command window. sorry. I am on Mac so where would my path name be?

Comment: this is where my collatz.m file is located:


/Users/farazbukhari/Google Drive/School/MATLAB/Programming Projects/Programming Project 4

Comment: Well, if you're working with the MATLAB GUI, there's a bar underneath the ribbon where you can paste this path (or, of course,just call  `cd  /Users/farazbukhari/.... Project`). If you're running the script through the terminal, see [`matlab`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabmac.html).

Comment: @Dev-iL okay thank you. got that sorted out. But now when I go to call the function, it doesn't give me any error messages. It just returns nothing.

Comment: Well, if you provide a negative number you'll be stuck in an infinite loop. Other than that, you seem to be overwriting `veclist` instead of adding elements to it. In MATLAB, adding elements is done by addressing increasing positions of a vector (preferably preallocated). In your example, `veclist = veclist + num;` should be `veclist = [veclist, num];` to start making sense...

Comment: @Dev-iL Okay I changed that part of my code and it is still not working. I am not gonna worry about the negative numbers in my code for now. Lets just say the user inputs only positive numbers.

It is still giving me nothing when I run collatz(5)

Comment: Try temporarily adding `fprintf(1, '%d %d', s, m)` at the end of your function. If you don't see anything printed, you are running the wrong code somehow.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I added that after the "end" that ended my function. It started giving me the "undefined function or variable 'collatz' " issue again.

Comment: You should add it *inside* the `end`. You cannot have a function file which contains code *not in a function*. It sounds like you're not even asking for MATLAB to output anything, you should be calling `[s,m] = collatz(num)`, not just `collatz(num)` which will store the resulting `s` in the generic variable `ans`. You haven't even shown us how you're trying to call this. [See this checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for things you should do before asking a question, in particular be specific.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your original question is that `collatz.m` was not on your MATLAB path. The easiest way to solve this is change the current directory (using the `cd` command) to wherever your file is located. E.g.

```
cd /Users/farazbukhari/Google Drive/School/MATLAB/Programming Projects/Programming Project
```

The reason why you get nothing is because you have an infinite loop. You said that your stopping condition is when the number "is equal to 1", then why does the `while` loop check for `0`? When the current code gets to `1` it just treats it as an odd number turns it to `4` then `2` then `1`then `4,2,1` ... *ad infinitum*.

The quick fix in this case is to change the loop condition to `while num > 1`.

Finally, you were not appending new values to your `veclist` correctly, which was resolved by changing it to `veclist = [veclist, num];` (although this is not ideal in terms of performance). Instead, you should preallocate a `veclist` of some reasonable size (e.g. `veclist = zeros(10*num,1)`), and keep a counter you increment, indicating the last position that was written to. This way you avoid creating increasingly large vectors as the solution progresses. In the end just trim all zero values from the end, by e.g. `veclist(veclist == 0) = [];`.

Comment: Okay I changed the while loop condition and I am still getting nothing when run "collatz(5)"

Comment: it looks like it is getting stuck on line 19 where I said

if num > 0

I do not understand why it is getting stuck here

Comment: My bad. It should be `while num > 1`. Also, the enclosing `if...end` statement is unnecessary.